# Hair particle guides remain the same after simulation

Tags: particles, hair

[image]

This is the hair guide I begin with.After simulation,it looks like this in object mode.

[image]

But when I switch back to particle edit mode,it is still picture one.

What should I do to get simulated hair guides ?
I accidentally saw the hair guides after the simulation a few times.What I want to achieve is to convert certain frame to hair guides in particle edit mode and make that frame 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it is not natively possible for now, but here is a [Heveti's script](https://blenderartists.org/t/apply-lock-hair-particles-after-hair-dynamics-simulation/635938/11?u=vklidu)

- switch to *Particle Edit* - **move at least one hair a bit to initiate hair editing**
- enable *Hair Dynamics* and *Play* animation to simulate hairs
- move to frame where dynamics should be applied
  lt- copy&paste script into blender's Text Editor and Run <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> script

Now when you switch to *Particle Edit*, hairs are at a position of your choice so you can continue with editing. Or enable Hair Dynamics again, move on start at Timeline and run simulation agin from this point of state.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
    import bpy

# How to use:
# 1. edit hair system (important, move at least one hair, at least a bit to initiate hair editing)
# 2. run hair dynamics
# 3. move to frame where dynamics should be applied
# 4. run script
# 5. if happy, delete cache
# 6. keep editing hair

# get the depsgraph and the evaluated object   
deps_graph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
evaluated_object = bpy.context.object.evaluated_get(deps_graph)
# assume context object has a particle system (warning, no check), use active
particle_system = evaluated_object.particle_systems.active

# Variable to hold hair-verticies-coordinats
hairs = []

# At current frame
# For each particle (hair)
#   For each vertex
#     Store XYZ coordinates
for p in particle_system.particles:
    hair = []
    for v in p.hair_keys:
        hair.append([v.co[0], v.co[1], v.co[2]])
    hairs.append(hair)

# Deactivate hair dynamics
particle_system.use_hair_dynamics = False

# On static hair system
# For each particle (hair)
#   For each vertex
#     Overwrite XYZ coordinates
for p,hair in zip(particle_system.particles,hairs):
    for v,h in zip(p.hair_keys,hair):
        #print(v.co, h)
        v.co[0] = h[0]
        v.co[1] = h[1]
        v.co[2] = h[2]
        #print(v.co, h)

# Update view and UI
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_current)
```

[image]